# making Visual Studio 2015 to use Windows SDK 10 instead of Windows SDK 8.1

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, sdk

I am compiling a code which has used Windows SDK 8.1. However I want to use Windows SDK 10 (10.0.14393.33) that I already have it installed. Where in project should I change this? I already have re-targeted the solution to use 10.0.14393.0

```
7>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\DbgHelp.h(1545): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared (compiling source file client_info.cc)
```

[image]

The project has been also upgraded to work in Visual Studio 2015 in the beginning.

[image]

Note that even though I have re-targeted the solution, it still is looking to use Windows SDK 8.1

Comment: Check the entries in the [VC++ Directories Property Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx).

Comment: You should use the Windows SDK configuration tool that comes with the SDK you installed.  it is the better way to modify the SDK used by VS.  But, i have to wonder why you want to do this?  If you use an API that is in Windows 10 but not in lower versions, any application you develop will not run in lower versions of Windows.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson: You've got this backwards. Conditionally using a Windows 10 API only where available will still enable a program to run on down-level systems. If, on the other hand, you are using a down-level SDK, you are left with fumbling structures and function declarations together yourself. Not entirely recommended.